# Appcache - fallback not working as expected

Tags: html, caching, html5-appcache

By providing `FALLBACK`, I expect the `wifi.svg` to be replaced with `nowifi.svg` when it is loaded from cache. it is not working as expected.

Here is my cache manifest file.

```
CACHE MANIFEST 
# Version 0.1.3


index.html

CACHE: 
images/nowifi.svg

NETWORK: 
images/wifi.svg

FALLBACK:
images/wifi.svg images/nowifi.svg
```

When I'm offline, I only see *missing image* in place of cached `nowifi.svg`

I thought, since I never request `nowifi.svg` could be the problem, just added a hidden `<img src="images/nowifi.svg" />` still no luck.

I could not able to figure out what is the issue.

For complete project: https://github.com/palaniraja/kmusic/blob/master/src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `wifi.svg` from the `NETWORK` section of your manifest, for the fallback to work:

```
CACHE MANIFEST 
#Version 0.1.3

index.html

CACHE: 
images/nowifi.svg

FALLBACK:
images/wifi.svg images/nowifi.svg
```

This might feel a bit counter-intuitive at first, but an explicit `NETWORK` entries take precedence over the fallback entries, which is why your fallback is never applied and the image is missing.

The browser is also smart enough to recognize that the left side of the `FALLBACK` entry is to be re-checked with the server, and will properly replace it with a fallback image (instead of just using a cached copy),
when it is offline.

It will also normally automatically cache the right hand side of the `FALLBACK` entry (i.e. `nowifi.svg`), so you may omit it from the `CACHE` section as well (through it won't affect anything).

Also note that in my experience the "Work Offline" functions of Google Chrome "Developer Tools" and Firefox, sometimes tend to produce all kind of weird results when it comes to cache and the offline apps, so you better just switch your web server or connection on and off instead, when testing this.

Comment: Thank you. The answer is not to use dev tools for testing. I almost replied you "no luck" without stopping the server :-)